# Horizontal scrolling Inside a DIV with Tables

Tags: html, css

I have three tables inside a div. I require horizontal and vertical scrolling when the size of the table increases. Vertical scrolling is happening but horizontal is not happening. Third table is coming in the next row and not with other tables. I am using three tables instead of one for responsive design.

```
<div style="height:250px; width:550px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y: scroll; white-space:nowrap;">
    <table border="1" style="float:left; table-layout:auto;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Pin Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>111111111111111111111111111</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>  
    <table border="1" style="float:left; table-layout:auto;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Pin Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>222222222222222222222222222</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>  
    <table border="1" style="float:left; table-layout:auto;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Pin Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>444444444444444444444444444</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>  
</div>
```

Comment: The way you have coded to achieve what you are looking for is very bad.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the each `table` with a `div` and use the below css

```
.wrapper{
  height:250px; 
  width:550px; 
  overflow:scroll; 
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.wrapper div{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kexuvabo/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`overflow: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;`